# Getting global information (Stack Exchange) about a list of users

Tags: support, feature-request, api-v2, users

I'm working with the API for several weeks (see my app [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/4467/truebadges-a-combination-of-stackexchange-badges-and-trueachievements)) and I'm trying to get the username of a particular user from its Stack Exchange ID.

It's possible by querying [/users/{ids}](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids) but it returns data from one website at a time, so it will require more requests to get data from multiple users if theirs accounts belong to different websites.

Example:

1. [Get the websites associated to my Account ID](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#page=1&pagesize=100&ids=2606599&filter=!*L3o7uonOjmsmzm%29&run=true) and store a website and its `user_id`
2. [Get the badges associated to my `user_id`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-on-users#order=desc&sort=rank&ids=2257664&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) (you may need to associate `site_URL` with `api_site_parameter`)

See how the `network_user` node is present in every badge.

If a global method (returning data from the Stack Exchange network) was available, it should require less requests since it would only take user ids and return only one note per user.

Am I missing something?

If this data is not available, is it possible to add a simple `/users/{ids}` which returns global data and not on a per-site basis?

Examples:

- Account #1 on Stack Overflow (ok): http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/1?site=stackoverflow
- Account #1 on Stack Exchange (the method does not exist): http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API path you want is [`/users/{ids}/associated`<sup>Doc</sup>](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users).
It takes global, Stack Exchange `account_id`s and returns all the site-specific `user_id`s for the specified users.

For example, your `user_id` for Stack Overflow is **2257664** and your global Stack Exchange, `account_id` is **2606599**.
(You can see your `/associated` results, [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=2606599&filter=!bc0qA99NA9KBW0&run=true).)

You can get user `account_id`s from any query that returns [`user` objects](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user).

Alas, the `/associated` paths have two big shortcomings.  Perhaps make these your specific feature requests:

1. [The `network_user` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/network-user) inexplicably **does not return the user's `display_name`** for each associated account!
2. The `/associated` paths require `account_id`, and only `account_id`.  This means that multiple queries must be used.
   A good feature would be if an `/associated` path accepted, say,
   `site=stackoverflow&user_id=2257664`
   as an alternate search parameter.

---

Currently, there is no way to do what you appear to want, without a whole lot of trivial queries.  Consider having your app build up, and cache, a table of frequently queried users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. **1.** The problem with `associated` is that it may return up to 100 results if the user registered on 100 websites, each with the same data replicated. So even if the `display_name` was available it would be a waste of bandwidth. **2.** *multiple queries*? You can use `1;2;3` to get multiple users. Anyway, I don't want to search on one website only.