# How to get user information of all sites merged

Tags: support

I'm actually using `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/${userID}?site=${site}` to get some user information from a specific site on Stack Exchange, **but I want to get the information for all sites that one user participates in**.

I've tried to use `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/${userID}/associated`, but it returns the information split by site, and I want it combined like the combined flair:

[image: profile for Diego Borba on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Have someway to do it, or must I combine it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no endpoint in the API that will give you user_info objects across the network.

The two end-points you've found is the way to go:

- fetch all associated network_users for a user
- call for each network_user per site /users/{userid} to collect the user_info objects for the other sites the user has a profile for.
- combine / merge the data you've fetched for your goal.

See also: [Getting global information (Stack Exchange) about a list of users](https://stackapps.com/questions/4493/getting-global-information-stack-exchange-about-a-list-of-users?rq=1)